# Impossible to uninstall certain apps in ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, uninstall, phone

I recently bought a bq smartphone ubuntu edition, and I was surprised to see so many pre installed apps that I don't want to use. Some of them are apparently easy to remove, by going to the ubuntu store.

But there is something that I don't manage to do. I'm in the Apps scope, and slide the screen upwards. Then, I see a screen with a list of the active scopes named "Home", and a second list named "Also Installed". In this list I see many apps that I don't manage to find in the ubuntu store, and therefore I cannot uninstall. For instance, 7 digital, Amazon, cnet, ebay... many of them.

But I'm not sure that the procedure of uninstalling them from the ubuntu store is really working: If I go to Settings->About this phone->Storage, I see a detailed list of the apps that are using memory in my phone. In this list there are some apps that I previously uninstalled using the ubuntu store procedure. For instance, BBC, BBC sport, facebook,facebook photos, Gmail... and many more are still using memory in my phone.

My question is: How can I really get rid of these apps that I don't want to have? I would like not to dedicate a single bit of space to those apps

Comment: https://open.uappexplorer.com/app/tweakgeek.mzanetti

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I try to share what I know about the 'also installed' secion:

If you swipe up in apps view, you can manage your scopes, not you apps. You can select there which scopes are placed to the right of your apps view.

Remember a scope is something like a search engine, which can be accessed by swiping from right to left in apps view.
Many scopes can be installed over the appsStore. But some scopes are installed together with other apps.

I guess, if you deinstall all apps, there would be no further scope listed in the 'also installed' section.